# How to change datatype on target table from Varchar(100) to 200 in oracle ODI without disturbing the existing interface?

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

I have source connection server and target connection server with datastores mapped. The process runs with a one flaw for one table and I noticed the target table has a column with datatype Varchar(100) and source table has column with varchar(200) but this needs to be changed to Varchar(200) because the target table truncates value after 100 character.

What is the best way to change?
A)In Oracle ODI - Models - Target Table - Attributes - Change Varchar from 100 to 200
B) Target Table server
C) Both

Btw, I am new to oracle ODI so please bear with me while I learn.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can alter the table structure at target table server using alter table statement.
And then, change the attribute in ODI model.

Comment: Cheers, thank you. I shall try in test environment.

Comment: I have done the above but the new value still does not reflect from source to target. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to go model/table and try to right click -> edit the column you want to change dataype and save it :)